# Custom properties for objects not showing in native share dialog

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I've added a custom property to my custom object in a Custom story on facebook.

When I edit the attachments and add my custom property as caption 2, it posts fine but does not show up on the native share dialog? So it would seem the user is mislead and would not realize the other information is going to post also. Any idea why the other caption does not show up?

```
candy.setProperty("og:description", "Caption 1");
candy.setProperty("mynamespace:summary2", "Caption 2");
```